# XGBOOST Error Running Model - DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category

Tags: python, null, xgboost

I am trying to run a model which uses XGBOOST algorithm. However, upon execution there are couple of rows which has Nonetype data type with all null values. This causes an error in the model execution, something like this -

```
"message":"Error running model: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category.  When\ncategorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must\nbe set to `True`. Invalid columns:X, Y
```

X and Y columns for this particular row has Null values. Is there any way to allow XGBOOST to process such a data type?

Tried to replace 'null' in X and Y to empty strings but doesn't work.

Comment: P.S. not possible to replace null with 0 as it will mess with the results

Comment: Null values is not a problem, the pandas column dtype is. To go any further we'd need some more details, preferably a minimal reproducible example.